# Correctly characterizing a result about the dot product under permutations

Tags: proof-writing, linear-transformations

In $\mathbb{R}^n$, I was able to prove that I can permute the components of a vector and preserve the dot product. The proof, for reference, is below.

> Let $T_{\sigma}: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a permutation sending $p = (p_1, \ldots, p_n) \mapsto (p_{\sigma(1)}, p_{\sigma(2)}, \ldots, p_{\sigma(n)})$ for some $\sigma \in S_n$. Let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and write $x = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ and $y = (y_1, \ldots, y_n)$. One then has
> \begin{align*}
> T_{\sigma} (x) \cdot T_{\sigma} (y) &= (x_{\sigma(1)}, x_{\sigma(2)}, \ldots, x_{\sigma(n)}) \cdot (y_{\sigma(1)}, y_{\sigma(2)}, \ldots, y_{\sigma(n)}) \\
> &= \sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_{\sigma(i)} \cdot y_{\sigma(i)} \\
> &= \sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i \cdot y_i \\
> &= x \cdot y. 
> \end{align*}
> I'm not sure how else to write the proof other than to say that I'm just using commutativity of addition to rearrange terms. Do I potentially write the indices as $\sigma^{-1} (\sigma(i))$.

I'm not sure how to characterize this result. Would I say that the dot product is invariant under permutation? I'm familiar with isometries, but I don't think a permutation $T$ qualifies as an isometry.

Answer (score 0):

Your characterization is reasonable. Given an inner product space $(V,\langle\:,\:\rangle)$, we say that a linear map $T:V\to V$ is an isometry (with respect to $\langle\:,\:\rangle$) if $\langle Tv,Tw\rangle = \langle v,w\rangle$ for all $v,w\in V$. The role of the inner product here is played by the dot product on $\Bbb{R}^n$. As a consequence, you showed
$$
\langle v,w\rangle = v\cdot w = T_\sigma v\cdot T_\sigma w = \langle T_\sigma v,T_\sigma w\rangle
$$
and consequently that a permutation matrix is an isometry of Euclidean space with the usual inner product.